# Sequelize: How to retrieve updated record after sequelize update query without using another query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

```
`    User.update({
  role: 'user'
}, {
  where: {
    email: email
  }
}).then(function(result) {
  //Returned value: either [0] or [1] i.e. record is updated or not
});
`
```

This is sequelize update query where User is model (user's role is updated by email). Its working fine but I want that using update query, I will get user's data as well. Is it possible to get it without using another query ?

Comment: Getting updated rows is only supported by postgresql

Answer (score 4):

Nope, not possible without another query. This isn't a limitation of Sequelize, it's a limitation of SQL. Under the hood, sequelize needs to do:

```
update users set role = 'user' where email = 'test@example.com'
```

which will just update the rows, but will not retrieve any rows. Then, it needs to do a second:

```
select * from users where email = 'test@example.com'
```

to actually get the (now updated) rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the updated value by calling this function `model.reload()`. Maybe will not work on older versions of Sequelize. Link to [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-instances/#reloading-an-instance).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using postgresql then you can set returning true after where clause

```
where: { socketID: socket.id },
  returning: true,
```

and and if you are using other db like mysql  as in my case then you cant to it in a single hit you have to use anther query like below

```
async function PersonalDetail(req, res) {
var Email = req.body.email;


    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { EmailAddress: Email, IsActive: true } });

    if (user != null) {
        user.UpdateDate = new Date();
        user.EmplomentID = req.body.EmplomentID;
        user.LivingID = req.body.LivingID;
        user.LocationID = req.body.LocationID;

        await user.save();

        res.json({
            IsSuccess: true,
            message: 'User updated',
            User: user
        });
    }
    else {
        res.json({
            IsSuccess: true,
            message: 'User Not updated',
            User: ""
        });
    }


}
```